# Speaker setup in Subaru Impreza

Tags: subaru, audio, speakers

I recently had an Alpine INE-W960A Navigation head unit and SPR-60C component speakers installed in my 2016 Impreza hatchback. As my budget was limited I did not replace the rear door speakers at the same time. I am now wishing to upgrade the rear speakers with Alpine SPR-60 co-axial speakers. there is a warning on the SPR-60 box stating- "This product contains a high performance tweeter. If there is a tweeter already installed in your car, then you must disconnect its terminals. If you leave the original tweeter connected and connect this product in parallel, then a fault may develop in this product, so you are strongly recommended not to do so." 
Should I return these speakers and if so which type of rear speakers should I purchase.

Answer (score 4):

That's a funny way to remind you that two tweeters - possibly out of phase - could result in a sound you're not happy with. Note this warning is specific to the channel (FL, FR, RL, RR) you're working in. If there are no rear tweeters then you're good. If there are rear tweeters you will definitely want to do two things

1. Disconnect the factory tweeters
2. Bypass any factory crossovers

A factory tweeter will almost always have a cap on it, so it's possible the woofer is not crossed over, but if it is, that tweeter on your coax isn't going to do much. In either case, you could be dealing with impedance issues at worst and terrible sound at best if you leave the factory tweeter hooked up along with the coax. Often the wires for both will be close to one another, so it might not be too bad finding the harness to disconnect the factory tweeter.

Comment: There are no individual factory tweeters on the rear channels so when the factory coaxial are replaced the new co axial will not be affected.  Perhaps the warning on the SPR-60 box should have been explained better. Thanks for your advice.